# What prophets are referred to in Deuteronomy 34:10?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, prophecies, parashat-vezot-habracha

[Deuteronomy 34:7-12](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.34.7-12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> Moses was one hundred twenty years old when he died; his sight was
> unimpaired and his vigor had not abated. 8 The Israelites wept for
> Moses in the plains of Moab thirty days; then the period of mourning
> for Moses was ended. 9 Joshua son of Nun was full of the spirit of
> wisdom, because Moses had laid his hands on him; and the Israelites
> obeyed him, doing as the Lord had commanded Moses. 10 **Never since
> has there arisen a prophet in Israel like Moses, whom the Lord knew
> face to face.** 11 He was unequaled for all the signs and wonders that
> the Lord sent him to perform in the land of Egypt, against Pharaoh and
> all his servants and his entire land, 12 and for all the mighty deeds
> and all the terrifying displays of power that Moses performed in the
> sight of all Israel.

Can we assume from the text that it refers to prophets from the time of Moses's death till the time of the author of the text, that had arisen but weren't like Moses (as mighty as him)?

Or maybe Joshua was inspired to say that after Moses died up till the moment he was writing this verse (some decades), never since has there arisen a prophet in Israel like Moses,(as mighty as him)

Means that though he himself "Joshua" was the only prophet that has been risen up till this moment but he can't be compared to the rank of the mighty Moses?

Comment: Another translation reads "Never again did there arise in Israel a prophet like Moses—whom the LORD singled out, face to face," a third has, "And there was no other prophet who arose in Israel like Moses, whom the Lord knew face to face".  The New Revised version is adding in its understanding.

Comment: I think whatever the translation is: the meaning depends on our convention, who is the writer of the passage. If Joshua then it means "after Moses died up till the moment he was writing this verse ,during the 40 of 50 years he held the prophethood after Moses, Never since has there arisen a prophet in Israel like Moses  "as mighty as him" even me "'Joshua""

Comment: If later than Joshua then it means "after Moses died up till the moment the writer was writing this verse , Never since has there arisen a prophet in Israel like Moses "as mighty as him" from the several prophets that  been risen. After Moses.  isn't it?

Comment: and if the writer wrote from the mouth of God then it is a statement that continues to be true as God speaks of all times.